# Steam, Torchlight 2 game doesnt start

Tags: games, steam, dbus

My system:
**CPU**: AMD FX 8320
**RAM**: 16 GB DDR3
**MOBO**: Asrock 970 pro 3
**GPU**: RX 580 8GB
**OS**: Ubuntu 17.10 / Kernel: 4.13.0-18
**Graphics Driver**: Mesa 17.3.0-rc4 DRM 3.18.0  LLVM 5.0.0 using padoka ppa

Before upgrading to a RX 580 8GB I used to have a Nvidia GTX 650 ti (with the nvidia drivers which I purged before switching cards)

When I used th GTX 650 ti this play used to play without any issue...

then I stopped playing it for a while and then I upgraded my graphics card to the RX 580 8GB (I dont know if this switch of GPU is related especially since I purged the older drivers but I just mention it for context)

Now the game doesnt boot at all when I click on it the launher appears as it used to in the past but when I click the "run" button on the launcher only the splash logo appears in the center of the screen for a few seconds and dissapears again and then **nothing happens**.

I also tried to delete and reinstall the game but nothing changed.

Here is what console puts out when starting steam and then imidiatelly try to start Torchlight II.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",



(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(steam:10141): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown device type 14

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1: unknown object type

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:10141): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
[1126/115658.360083:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
[1126/115659.361092:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
roaming config store loaded successfully - 2908 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store

(steam:10141): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'child-added' is invalid for instance '0x57a6a100' of type 'GtkMenu'
[1126/115700.362256:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
process 10141: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1201.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/papajo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam'"
System startup time: 5.03 seconds
Generating new string page texture 74: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1.49 MB
Generating new string page texture 75: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
Generating new string page texture 76: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.62 MB
Generating new string page texture 77: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.88 MB
Generating new string page texture 78: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1.95 MB
Generating new string page texture 79: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1.98 MB
Generating new string page texture 87: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2.11 MB
Generating new string page texture 88: 256x256, total string texture memory is 2.38 MB
Generating new string page texture 90: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2.51 MB
[1126/115701.363365:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197992848297 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)

(steam:10141): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: About to Show called on an item wihtout submenus.  We're ignoring it.
Generating new string page texture 101: 24x256, total string texture memory is 2.53 MB
[1126/115702.364852:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Generating new string page texture 144: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction[AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Opted-in Controller Mask: 0
Game update: AppID 200710 "Torchlight II", ProcID 10260, IP 0.0.0.0:0
>>> Adding process 10260 for game ID 200710
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/papajo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/papajo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Game update: AppID 200710 "Torchlight II", ProcID 10262, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 200710
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197992848297 [API loaded no]
GameAction [AppID 200710, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
>>> Adding process 10261 for game ID 200710
>>> Adding process 10262 for game ID 200710
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/papajo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 10265 for game ID 200710
Game update: AppID 200710 "Torchlight II", ProcID 10265, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 200710
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197992848297 [API loaded no]
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group Internal
Creating resource group Autodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Font
ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
DDS codec registering
FreeImage version: 3.13.1
This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,bay,bmq,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,dng,erf,fff,hdr,k25,kdc,mdc,mos,mrw,nef,orf,pef,pxn,raf,raw,rdc,sr2,srf,arw,3fr,cine,ia,kc2,mef,nrw,qtk,rw2,sti,drf,dsc,ptx,cap,iiq,rwz
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
Loading library RenderSystem_GL
Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
Plugin successfully installed
Loading library Plugin_OctreeSceneManager
Installing plugin: Octree & Terrain Scene Manager
Plugin successfully installed
*-*-* OGRE Initialising
*-*-* Version 1.7.0 (Cthugha)
Path for saving is ... /home/papajo/.local/share/Runic Games/Torchlight 2/save
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/papajo/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 10277 for game ID 200710
FMOD detects no hardware acceleration!
SoundManager Initialized
>>> Adding process 10278 for game ID 200710
ArchiveFactory for archive type PAK registered.
Creating resource group PAK
Added resource location 'MEDIA/PARTICLES/TEXTURES/' of type 'PAK' to resource group 'PAK' with recursive option
Added resource location 'MEDIA/UI/' of type 'PAK' to resource group 'General' with recursive option
Added resource location 'MEDIA/TRANSLATIONS/' of type 'PAK' to resource group 'General' with recursive option
Added resource location 'MEDIA/SHAREDTEXTURES/' of type 'PAK' to resource group 'General' with recursive option
Added resource location './' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'General'
Creating resource group MUSIC
Added resource location 'music/' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'MUSIC'
Creating resource group MODMUSIC
Added resource location '/home/papajo/.local/share/Runic Games/Torchlight 2/MEDIA/MUSIC/' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'MODMUSIC'
Parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
Finished parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
Parsing scripts for resource group General
Finished parsing scripts for resource group General
Parsing scripts for resource group Internal
Finished parsing scripts for resource group Internal
Parsing scripts for resource group MODMUSIC
Finished parsing scripts for resource group MODMUSIC
Parsing scripts for resource group MUSIC
Finished parsing scripts for resource group MUSIC
Parsing scripts for resource group PAK
Finished parsing scripts for resource group PAK
Creating resource group Shaders
Added resource location 'programs/' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'Shaders' with recursive option
Compressing memory size is: 246
Compressing memory size is: 4559
MovableObjectFactory for type 'PUParticleSystem' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BoxSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'SphereSet' registered.
Compressing memory size is: 17309
Compressing memory size is: 177722
GUID of room piece  is not unique in alias set: INFECTED_ESTHSHRINE. Room piece guid is: -3691357540205283053
GUID of room piece  is not unique in alias set: INFECTED_ESTHSHRINE. Room piece guid is: -8499989545814233359
GUID of room piece  is not unique in alias set: TUNDRA_SNOW. Room piece guid is: 6465848823990489780
CPU Identifier & Features
-------------------------
 *   CPU ID: AuthenticAMD: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
 *      SSE: yes
 *     SSE2: yes
 *     SSE3: yes
 *      MMX: yes
 *   MMXEXT: yes
 *    3DNOW: no
 * 3DNOWEXT: no
 *     CMOV: yes
 *      TSC: yes
 *      FPU: yes
 *      PRO: yes
 *       HT: no
-------------------------
Setting YRatio Init - 1.40625
GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "Torchlight II v.1.25.5.4", 1920x1080 windowed  miscParams: FSAA=2 border=fixed highdpi=0 left=0 top=0 vsync=1 
Could not make screen: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
Game removed: AppID 200710 "Torchlight II", ProcID 10265 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 10141: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
```